# Why do my questions get no answers or comments?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

[How to make Lubuntu's Temperature Monitor applet report the real temperatures inside my PC instead of always "thermal_zone0: 40°C"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/924710/)

[How to unbind the Super or Logo key so it may be used by applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/969628/)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No one knows the answer(s)

Comment: You posted [How to unbind the Super or Logo key so it may be used by applications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/969628/22949) just six hours ago. Sometimes questions are answered or commented on that soon, but often not. Is the other question you've mentioned here, [How to make Lubuntu's Temperature Monitor applet report the real temperatures inside my PC instead of always “thermal_zone0: 40°C”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/924710/22949), the only one that has sat around for a long time without attention? Are there other examples or are you really just asking about those two questions?

Comment: you switched frm lubuntu to kubuntu, does the answer to the first question still matters? besides https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature scroll down to the conky answer.  If it can't be done using the default widget, it doesn't mean there's no alternative. and this is for your second question https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key

Answer (score 1):

No you are not doing anything wrong. But that is only 2 questions they might have gone unnoticed or the people that viewed it don't know the answer. Keep posting to Ask Ubuntu and you will get answered. :)

Comment: BTW, if you were doing something wrong you would get   flagged.